# Prove that the limit is zero given integral is zero.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(t)$ be a real-valued function that is continuous, positive, and increasing on the real interval $(0,T)$. If
$$\int_0^T {\dfrac{f(s)}{s} ds} < \infty, $$
prove that $\lim_{t \to 0} f(t)= 0.$

I only have an intuitive idea of why this is true: if the conclusion does not hold, $f(s)/s$ will go to infinity as $s$ approaches zero. In this case, the integral cannot converge.

I would like a more rigorous solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is slightly off. Consider the integral $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{s^p} ds$$ for $0<p<\infty$. It is well known that this integral diverges if $p\geq 1$, and converges if $p<1$. Yet $1/s^p$ is a function going to $\infty$ as $s\to 0$.

There is, however, a rigorous reason why the claim holds. Suppose, aiming for contradiction, that  $\lim_{t\to 0} f(t) = c > 0$. Since $f$ is increasing on $(0,T)$, $f(t)\geq c$ for all $t\in(0,T)$. This implies that
$$ \infty > \int_0^T \frac{f(s)}{s}ds \geq \int_0^T \frac{c}{s}ds = c\int_0^T \frac{1}{s}ds = \infty.$$
This is a contradiction.

As an easy exercise, you should determine where I used the continuity of $f$.

Comment: I'm guessing you used the continuity of $f$ to say that its right-hand limit at $0$ exists? Is this correct?

Comment: Almost - technically the function could be unbounded. So we have to pull in increasing and positive as well.